# loop a list through a function

Tags: python, function, loops

I have two functions as such:

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

```
def category_mode(df,x):
    newdf=df[df['Availability2']!='2']
    newdf=newdf.dropna(subset=[x])
    newdf=newdf[[x,'Availability2']]
    newdf=newdf.groupby([x, 'Availability2'])['Availability2'].count().unstack()
    newdf.loc['Total', :] = newdf.sum().values
    newdf['Total']=newdf.groupby(x).sum().sum(axis=1)
    newdf['Availability']=newdf['0']/newdf['Total']*100
    newdf=newdf.reset_index()
    return newdf
```

```
def create_catplot(newdf,val):
    x=newdf[val]
    y=newdf['Total']
    y1=newdf['Availability']
    g = sns.barplot(x=x, y=y, color='blue')
    g2 = sns.lineplot(x=range(len(x)), y=y1, color='orange', marker='o', ax=g.axes.twinx())
    g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
    g.set_xlabel(val)
    g.set_ylabel('Total')
    g2.set_ylabel('Availability')
    g.legend(handles=[Rectangle((0,0), 0, 0, color='blue', label='Recipe Counts'), Line2D([], [], marker='o', color='orange', label='Availability')], loc=(1.1,0.8))
```

The function works if I'm using one element in this case `'RecipeName'`, but I have to call it multiple times if I have other parameters, how can I pass the other parameters as a list in `category_mode` have them called and store them as variables and then use those stored variables to call `create_catplot`?

list for example

```
li=['Format','RecipeName','MachineState','MachineMode']
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? E.g. how each element of your list should be passed to thwse functions and how you use the functions together.  A working example would really help answering.

Comment: I basically want to apply the same function to the other names, basically format, machinestate and machinemode without calling the function for each individual element. I want to call them all together in the interest of saving time and not making it repetitive.

Comment: the output of the first function(variable newdf) is fed as input to function 2.

Comment: would you be so kind to edit my functions with your answer, it would be really helpful for me to try it out. thank you.

Comment: I still think your question is very unclear, say you had one string, how would you run your code for that single input?

Comment: I would run it as such ```var1=category_mode(owerritable,'RecipeName') ``` and then follow it with ```create_catplot(var1,'RecipeName')```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to do that:

```
def call_process(df, li):
   if type(li) is list:
      for i in li: 
         create_catplot(category_mode(df,i), i)
   else: 
      create_catplot(category_mode(df,li), li)
```

and pass your input variable `li` (whether it is a list or a string) to the function.

Comment: val in this case is however the individual element of the list, would this still work?

Comment: Write how you would call the functions with a single string, e.g. 'RecipeName'

Comment: ```call_process(owerritable,'MachineState',li=['Format','RecipeName','MachineState','MachineMode'])```, I tried this but it doesnt work.

Comment: Changed the function according to your clarification. See if the new function works. You may want to update your question, to make a working example.

Comment: Why would you use a list comprehension for that?!  Why return the variable `true`?

Comment: I first wrote the whole as a single liner. Fixed as suggested.